# How to access query string in nuxtjs and pass it to data

Tags: vue.js, nuxtjs

I want to access query strings from url in nuxtjs page.
this is the page url with query strings -

```
http://localhost:3000/en-IN/atrsps/results/?pickupairport=Dubai&dropoffpoint=Bur%20Dubai,%20DU,%20United%20Arab%20Emirates&pickupdate=06%2F06%2F2021%2013%3A27
```

this is the my page script part

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      cars: [],
      loading: false,
      disabled: true,
      pickupairport: null,
      dropoffpoint: null
    }
  },
  asyncData({ route }) {
      console.log(route.query)
  },
  computed: {
    url() {
      return `https://api.testdomain.com/V2/transfers/carlist?startpoint=${this.pickupairport}&endpoint=${this.dropoffpoint}&pickupdate=2021-07-01&pickuptime=14:55`
    },
  },
  
  async created() {
    await this.fetchData()
  },

  methods: {
    async fetchData() {
      this.loading = true //the loading begin
      const res = await axios.get(this.url)
      this.cars = res.data.response
      this.loading = false
    },
    carsearch($state) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        axios
          .get(this.url)
          .then((res) => {
            if (res.data.response.length > 1) {
              res.data.response.forEach((item) => this.cars.push(item))
              $state.loaded()
            } else {
              $state.complete()
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
          })
      }, 1000)

    },
  },
}
</script>
```

I want to pass pickupairport and dropoffpoint value from url to pickupairport & dropoffpoint in data.

in console, i can see this data

```
 {                                                                                                                                                 
  pickupairport: 'Dubai',
  dropoffpoint: 'Bur Dubai, DU, United Arab Emirates',
  pickupdate: '06/06/2021 13:27'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the template you can access to it from `$route` object like `$route.query` and from the vue instance you can write `this.$route.query`

also you can check the `$route` object from vue dev tools. check out the picture below:

[image]

to pass the queries to data object you can just write:

```
data() {
  return {
    pickupairport: this.$route.query.pickupairport,
  }
}
```

but you might not need to store the query in data object since you have access to `$route` object either from template or anywhere in your script